# Multiple looped ajax requests with one callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dry

Like in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/), I have several ajax requests to perform followed by 1 action.
However, the difference is that all my ajax request only differ by one incremental parameter like this:

```
        $.when(
            // ajax requests
            // 1
            $.ajax({
                url:"https://www.aaaaaaa.com?param="+0,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (response) {
                    data = data.concat(response);
                }
            }),
            // 2
            $.ajax({
                url:"https://www.aaaaaaa.com?param="+2500,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (response) {
                    data = data.concat(response);
                }
            }),
            // 3
            $.ajax({
                url:"https://www.aaaaaaa.com?param="+5000,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (response) {
                    data = data.concat(response);
                }
            })
            // etc. ~10 times

        ).then(function() {
            // action
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Like python I don't like to repeat myself 10 times.
I tried to make a for loop but it seems not possible to write for loops in the $.when().

Any ideas how to achieve this ?
I searched everywhere whithout results.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should probably work is to define a function before your $.when something like this:

```
function createRequest(port) {
     return $.ajax({
         url:"https://www.aaaaaaa.com?param="+port,
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success: function (response) {
             data = data.concat(response);
         }
     })
}
```

and then use that in your $.when

```
$.when(createRequest(0), createRequest(2500), createRequest(5000));
```

And if you want to create this function call dynamically with more parameters you can create an array of these requests for-loop and then call $.when.apply(this, array)

```
$.when.apply(this, your_request_array)
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kriskowal's q implementation : https://github.com/kriskowal/q

there is a method `Q.allSettled(arrayOfPromises)` that suits your needs.

eg :

```
Q.allSettled(promises)
.then(function (results) {
  results.forEach(function (result) {
      if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
          var value = result.value;
      } else {
          var reason = result.reason;
      }
  });
});
```

Angular has based his `$q` directive on this

Answer (score 0):

Just put your promises in an array:

```
var promises = [0, 2500, 5000].map(function(n) {
    return $.ajax(...);    // appending `n` to the URL as required
});
```

and then call `$.when.apply`:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(...)
```

The parameters passed to the `.then` callback will be individual arrays, each containing the three parameters that a single `$.ajax` callback receives.

BTW, your current code will concat the arrays in whatever order the calls complete, not necessarily in the order they were started.

*If* the order of concatenation matters, you should use those `.then` function parameters rather than your existing `success` handlers to create your `data` variable:

```
then(function() {
    var data = [];
    [].forEach.apply(arguments, function(response) {
        data = data.concat(response[0]);
    });
});
```